# Adding days to a date in a loop, javascript

Tags: javascript

I feel like there is something I'm missing about this, I'm trying to add 7 days to a current date, then 14, then 21. What I'm ending up with is a compounding of intervals rather than current date + 7, then current date + 14 etc.

```
var date = new Date();

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                var tempDate = date;
                var repeatson = tempDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (i*7));
                var repeats = new Date(repeatson);
                console.log(repeats);
                }
```

Results in:

```
"2015-03-17T21:03:13.326Z"
"2015-03-24T21:03:13.326Z"
"2015-04-07T20:03:13.326Z"
"2015-04-28T20:03:13.326Z"
```

Rather than the desired, 24th, 31st & 8th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var tempDate = date;` simply assigns a *reference* to `date`. You are not creating a copy. Similarly, `setDate` does not return a new date, it mutates the date itself.

One solution would be to create a copy:

```
var tempDate = new Date(date);
```

Your loop could be simplified to

```
var repeats = (new Date(date)).setDate(date.getDate() + (i*7))
```